# Clicking with Spectron

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, electron, selenium-chromedriver, spectron

I have rendered two `tr` elements onto a browser window. I'd like to click the second one. Based on the webdriver docs, I figured the code would be as follows (using ava):

```
test('onclick should fire', async t => {
  const [, tr] = await t.context.app.client.$$('tr')
  await tr.click()
  t.true(/* some assertion */)
})
```

but this yields the following error:

```
  Rejected promise returned by test. Reason:

  TypeError {
    message: 'tr.click is not a function',
  }
```

Checking out some other stack posts, you can click a selector via it's xPath:

```
await t.context.app.client.click('//button')
```

And this actually works, but I'd prefer the first method, whereby you use a selector to choose an element, then call the `click` method on it. Is this possible?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?